# Grammatically , when can we use "you is" instead of "you are"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, british-english

Can we say "you is" instead of "you are"?

For example;

> "You is smart"

Comment: Based on the answers below and your specification of "grammatically" the answer is therefore "never" in correct English.

Comment: Agreed - it's wrong and you should never say it, even if you hear native speakers saying it.

Answer (score 5):

The only time you would hear "you is" for "you are" is in dialect forms of English. It is incorrect in standard English.

Answer (score 1):

When you are teaching someone that *'you' is a pronoun which has no singular form in Modern English*.

Comment: Excellent. Or as [lyrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is_You_Is_or_Is_You_Ain%27t_My_Baby).

Answer (score 1):

There is a time where using "you is" is correct. That situation is when you are speaking about the actual word "you." For example,

> The definition of *you* is ‘a pronoun used to refer to the person or people that the speaker is addressing.'

Other than that, *you* is a pronoun which has no singular form.

Answer (score 0):

*Is* is singular, whereas *are* is plural.

Here is the simple answer from a question asked on [ELU:](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200673/why-do-we-say-you-are-when-you-is-singular-instead-of-you-is)

> "you" is always plural. Or at least, it was so historically, and that has carried over into the present in verb conjugation.

The other answer that post offers:

> is that "are" is the form of "to be" used for first person plural, third person plural, and both plural and singular in second person (with you). Thus, "are" with a singular "you" is also singular. It just looks exactly like the plural form. The same goes for "were" in the past tense, or for any other verb in second person: The form of the singular is identical to that of the plural.

Although I do think this isn't as simple.

In modern times, *you is* has crept in as a colloquialism (presumably stemming from this confusion), but is considered incorrect.

Comment: You always takes are but it can refer to one person or to a group of people.

Answer (score 0):

"You is" is usually ungrammatical in standard English.  You cannot use "you is" as a substitute for "you are".

However, you can say "One of you is responsible", "One of you is stupid", "One of you is innocent".

Comment: That's because in the above sentences the subject is 'one' and not 'you'.